# How to capitalize first letter of textarea HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie in web programming and I am looking for a way to capitalize just the first letter of a textarea. I've already tried this solution found on the web but it doesn't work.

```
<p class="textarea_part">
    <textarea name="#" placeholder="La tua richiesta"></textarea>
</p>

<style>
    .textarea_part::first-letter {
         text-transform: capitalize;
     }
</style>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're targeting the paragraph element, not the textarea. Try using `.textarea_part textarea::first-letter` instead.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's actually `.textarea_part textarea` without the :first-letter:

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958901/css-first-letter-on-textarea-does-not-work/47958927

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Css ::first-letter on textarea does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958901/css-first-letter-on-textarea-does-not-work)

Comment: @Clvckl3s I meant what I wrote, considering the OP's requirements.

Comment: @NotTrixxie it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using javascript:

```js
document.querySelector('.textarea_text').addEventListener('input', () => {
  text = document.querySelector('.textarea_text').value;
  document.querySelector('.textarea_text').value = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
})
```

```html
<p class="textarea_part">
    <textarea name="#" placeholder="La tua richiesta" class="textarea_text"></textarea>
</p>
```

Thanks, @marcus-parsons for informing me of the `input` event listener! It's much faster for the javascript method now.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my answer!

Comment: Except the user wanted only the first letter capitalized, not the first letter of every word, which is what `capitalize` does.

Comment: In this way all the typed words have got the capital letter. Instead, i would like to have just the first letter of the first word capitalized.

Comment: And the CSS version doesn't actually modify the value to have the first letter capitalized, Clvckl3s. I would remove that from the answer.  Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate my point (look at the console output): https://jsfiddle.net/9te2b5cd/

Comment: Ok well then @SimoneArgento the javascript method should work for you

Comment: ok @MarcusParsons

Comment: @Clvckl3s where i have to put the JS code? In the HTML page or on a different JS file?

Comment: Both same html page and different js file works

Comment: @Clvckl3s I can't make it work. I have just written the JS on my html file but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Clvckl3s Ok, now it works. I had to modify the code removing the dot of ('textarea'). I ask you to upate your answer so I can close the post. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yeah for future readers: dot is for class, hashtag is for id, so the code thought of class called textarea

Comment: Also for future readers who are perhaps using this for non-ASCII text: `charAt(0)` may not work for you. I suggest ...`.value = [...text].map((c, i) => i === 0 ? c.toLocaleUpperCase() : c).join('');` to help mitigate language-specific problems.